# What exactlly is lock with adopt_lock_t

Tags: c++11, locking, mutex, unique-lock, lock-guard

When I checked [adopt_lock_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_tag_t),
it says `adopt_lock_t   assume the calling thread already has ownership of the mutex`.

So what's the meaning of the word `assume`? What if other thread already holding the mutex when I claim the lock(adopt_lock_t) with the same mutex?

Comment: Is this a better comment? https://cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/adopt_lock/

Answer (score 1):

If the assumption is wrong, the program's behavior is not constrained by the C++ standard.

So don't get it wrong.

What happens?  That is outside of what the standard dictates.  Anything.  A compliant C++ compiler could check for that condition and, if true, transfer your web browsing history to your parents.  Or it could crash.  Or deadlock.  Or your hard drive could be formatted.

As a matter of QoI, what would most likely happen is a crash, or your concurrency code being nonsense (an underflow on a lock counter maybe).  The C++ standard states that implementors are not responsible for any kind of reasonable behavior there, and compilers are free to optimize based on the assumption the lock is already held.

The most likely implementation is that the constructor doesn't lock the mutex, but does unlock in the destructor.  What happens when you unlock a mutex in a thread that doesn't have it locked, be it locked in another thread or not, is going to be implementation dependent.